HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory does not accept type CloseableHttpClient as params
I'm currently trying to fix my RestTemplate to avoid checking the SSL certificate to call my symfony project. So here's my code :
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                    .loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> true)
                    .build();

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                    .build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

I'm trying to avoid SSL check, but when I create a new instance of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory in my function, I have an error because my parameter is not of type HttpClient but CloseableHttpClient. Can someone help me? I'm putting just below my imports and my dependencies.
Imports :
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

Dependencies :
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

So as I said, this code is to avoid any checks on the SSL certificate because it's for a school project
Thank you for your help!

In my opinion the problem is not the server, the client is the problem, I think you can add your autosigned certificate to your local java cacert in order to consume that service and everything is solved.

Exactly. You’re solving the wrong problem. You don’t want to lower your security.

import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;

Spring is expecting a different interface,  org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient.  It looks like your dependencies need review.
Note:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>

